# Skip last Html row text box value and select on print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a query which inserts the data in to Mobile sqlite data base say for now i have three rows in a html table on button press a query is generated where it selects the value of the text box and the select selected value but the problem is on print it should skip the last rows value as in my case that is a auto increment table where a last row is left blank to fill in the data for the user.

Now

`INSERT INTO demo (xxxx, xxxxx, xxxx,xxxx,xxxx) VALUES ("Mickey1","Mouse1","No Match"),("Mickey2","Mouse2","No Match"),("skip row","skip row","No Match");`

Expected

`INSERT INTO demo (xxxx, xxxxx, xxxx,xxxx,xxxx) VALUES ("Mickey1","Mouse1","No Match"),("Mickey2","Mouse2","No Match");`

[Demo Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czv30xsq/)

JS

```
function Get() {
  var html = '';
  var arr = [];
  $('tr').each(function() {
    var inputs = $('input', this);
          var selects = $('select :selected', this);
    arr.push('("' + inputs[0].value + '","' + inputs[1].value + '","' + selects[0].text + '")');
  });

  html = 'INSERT INTO demo (xxxx, xxxxx, xxxx,xxxx,xxxx) VALUES ' + arr.join(',') + ';';
  $('#data').html(html);
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="Form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey1">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse1">
            </td>
                   <td>Last name:
             <select name="select2">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey2">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse2">
            </td>
                </td>
                   <td>Last name:
             <select name="select2">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>skip row
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="skip row">
            </td>
            <td>skip row
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="skip row">
            </td>
                </td>
                   <td>skip row
             <select name="select2">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="Get();" />
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the index parameter to the `each` function you can edit your code to only display specific lines.

```
$('tr').each(function(index, me) {
  if(index < $('tr').length - 1) {
    var inputs = $('input', me);
    var selects = $('select :selected', me);
    arr.push('("' + inputs[0].value + '","' + inputs[1].value + '","' + selects[0].text + '")');
  }
});
```

Also in `each` functions I believe `this` is not recommended. Adding the second argument to the function should act like `this` for the individual row (as I've have used `me`).

Here is a forked version of your Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/szkp0Lwq/1/

**Edit**

As per your comment below -

If you first want to validate your inputs you can do something like -

```
var valid = true;
$('tr').each(function(index, me) {
  if(index < $('tr').length - 1 && valid) {
    var inputs = $('input', me);
    inputs.each(function(index, me) {
      if($(me).val().length == 0)
        valid = false;
    });
    var selects = $('select', me);
    selects.each(function(index, me) {
      if($(me)[0].selectedIndex == 0)
        valid = false;
    });
    if(valid)
      arr.push('("' + inputs[0].value + '","' + inputs[1].value + '","' + $(selects[0]).val() + '")');
  }
});
if(valid)
  ..... submit query
else 
  alert("Form isn't valid!");
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/o4b1rLns/2/

Comment: If u dont mind i have a small question  i mean a little help

Comment: oops sorry for late reply the problem is it should same skip the last row and check if there are any text box or left blank  and the select value is not the first option expect last row

Comment: Ok, this updated answer should help though you should probably update your question to reflect the validation requirement also.

Comment: if you don't mint can you just update fiddle i tried in all possible ways but that is not working

Comment: Ok, the select validation was incorrect, I've updated.

Comment: @JohnC Hi John Need  your help can you help me if possible i think u can solve this

Comment: Ok @Shaik you have a question you want me to look at?

Comment: @JohnC can u create me a stack msg am not able to create so that i can explin to u what is about i think u can understand my problem more precisely as my question is little complex according to me i haven't posted any question wanted to talk to u first

Comment: Sorry for keeping u wait am in chat

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the row when you build the array, or only add the ones that doesnt have the "skip row" value, as below:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
var inputs = $('input', this);
      var selects = $('select :selected', this);
  if (inputs[0].value != "skip row") {
      arr.push('("' + inputs[0].value + '","' + inputs[1].value + '","' + selects[0].text + '")');
  }  
});
```